# Assign Java syntax to Blackberry tag

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

Programming questions tagged [blackberry](/questions/tagged/blackberry) will normally relate to Java (since BlackBerry applications are written in Java).

Can we adjust the syntax highlighting so that [blackberry](/questions/tagged/blackberry) questions are syntax-highlighted as Java?

Comment: Bad timing ... the new ["BlackBerry 10"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_10) can be programmed in lots of ways, but *not* in Java (except by writing Android apps).

Comment: Curse you RIM! Ok, I guess it's not cut-and-dry then. I'll delete the request!

Comment: @Azik Android has Java syntax highlighting. Beside the point, though, I don't think this is a dependable link. If someone asks a question in Blackberry with code, they will also likely tag Java.

Comment: @DuncanJones: I don't think you need to delete it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Can you post an answer containing the essence of your comment and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DuncanJones I would avoid deleting it. You can edit it to say it's a bad idea, but it can still stand as a reference for others.

Comment: @Telthien: Please don't edit questions to include stuff which belongs in answers. Thanks.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I didn't edit this post?

Comment: @Telthien: No, but you suggested doing so.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I see no such suggested edit in my activity log.

Comment: @Telthien: No, but you said that Duncan Jones should edit the question.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I think one's own opinion on a question is relevant to that question. If their opinion changed, they should indicate so.

Comment: @Telthien: Via an answer, yes. And if an answer from someone else contains that change of mind, it is enough to accept that answer to indicate that you're accepting that it was a bad idea (or similar).

Comment: I agree with @SulfurizedDemonbobby, upon further reflection. Accepting the answer should be the way I express agreement with the contrary view.

Comment: @Telthien, those of us who actively participate in the `blackberry` tag (none of whom have yet to comment on this question), **specifically** steer people away from using the `java` tag, because whenever you do that, a bunch of standard Java people jump in and offer solutions, completely oblivious to the fact that most modern Java APIs are not available on BlackBerry Java (which is 1.3, for the most part).  Even tagging with `java-me` isn't perfect, although most of us consider that vastly better than tagging with `java`.

Comment: Does the `java-me` tag not get Java syntax by default? This seems like an obvious choice for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While "old school" Blackberry OS development happens *mostly* in Java (you can write pure native applications as well), the new [BlackBerry 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_10) release does **not** natively support Java applications (it can run Android applications however).

Blackberry 10 does not currently seem to have lots of questions (probably because the devices are still pretty new, but I *suspect* it to overtake the classical BlackBerry questions in volume rather quickly.

Comment: I have very consistently tagged BlackBerry-10 questions with the BlackBerry-10 tag.  "BlackBerry" is, and always will be, for the legacy Java-ME based BlackBerry platform.

Comment: Additionally, agreeing that both platforms get the "BlackBerry" tag is bowing down to marketing departments, flying in the face of technological understanding of categories.  The legacy BlackBerry platform has zero commonality with BlackBerry-10, except for the company that currently owns the intellectual property of each platform.  Imagine "DOS" and "X-Box" having the same tag due to common ownership by Microsoft. Nonsense.   Equating BlackBerry and BlackBerry-10 is equally nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real question is whether the `blackberry` tag will, or should be, reserved for *legacy* BlackBerry (OS 4 - 7) development.  Or, will it now be used to cover BlackBerry 10 development, too.

If it's only going to be used for legacy BB Java development (which is by far the dominant BB development model, pre-BB10), then I vote for making Java syntax highlighting automatic.  I can't tell you [how often I edit BlackBerry questions](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor?userid=119114) just to add the `<!-- language-all: lang-java -->` markup, because unhighlighted code is almost unreadable, especially when sloppy posters clutter it up with a bunch of stuff that's commented out ... the code prettify function nicely identifies commented-out code.

If the tag, however, should be used for BB-10, and beyond, then Java syntax highlighting should *not* be activated.

Note that there is already a `blackberry-10` tag, and it seems to be getting some use.

I think I would cast my vote for making Java highlighting automatic for `blackberry`, [and a comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15921708/119114) by [another Top-10 BlackBerry answerer, Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blackberry/topusers), seems to agree (with the part about `blackberry` being for BB Java).

Comment: I am also in the top 10 list, and strongly agree with separation of BlackBerry and BlackBerry-10 by the tags.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue, yeah, even RIM/BlackBerry themselves are trying to establish that "BlackBerry 10" is a whole new thing, rather than simply the next version of the OS.  Maybe similar to Mac OS X, where version 10 was a major overhaul of the OS.  The BB 10 split is probably even more of a difference from its predecessors.

Comment: Is it worth considering re-branding the blackberry tag to "blackberry-legacy" or similar?

Comment: @DuncanJones, I think the only concern I'd have with that is that for tags to really be used properly, they need to be obvious and intuitive.  People like Michael, or myself, who spend lots of time curating the BB content, could adapt to such a tagname.  But, newbies, who generate most of the questions, are unlikely to think to use that tagname ... unless SO has some features I'm not aware of, whereby it can dynamically react as you type in tags, and suggest replacements.  More than just normal autocompletion.